# How can I filter someone else's list of contacts in LinkedIn by location?

Tags: linkedin

When I view someone else's list of contacts in LinkedIn, if I want to filter these by location or other variable...is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn doesn't provide a direct way to do this. 
Use [Advanced Search](http://www.linkedin.com/search?trk=advsrch) and customize it to 2nd level connections (Relationship filter), you can also add geographical location, company etc..